# Searching Multiple Tables in database

Tags: php, search

How to search multiple tables for a keyword regardless of which table or column it would be in?

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This is not how relational databases work.

Comment: Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow! This forum is not for questions about technologies or to find somebody doing the work for free (search some freelance service for that). See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas about what kind of questions can be made and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for information relating to for example a name or phrase which maybe in one or multiple tables in any column.